# Color swatch on compare page in magento2

Tags: magento2

Magento2

```
 How can be get the color swatch on product compare page..
```

Answer (score 1):

To have color swtach on product compare page you need to create custom module:-
Create a layout file with the name as catalog_product_compare_index.xml and add below code in the file created.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Magento_Swatches::css/swatches.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.list">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">W3solver_Compareswatch::product/compare/list.phtml</argument>
                </action>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                    <block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" as="configurable" template="Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml" />
                </block>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

You need to add one function in your overriden list.phtml on line 63

```
<?php 
    if($_item->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
        echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_item);
    endif;
?>
```

This will show the color patches on compare page.